# Does SMTP XOAUTH2 work when sending email using Google Services Account. It always returns: 555 5.5.2 Syntax error, goodbye. iy1-8plb.26 - gsmtp

Tags: java, google-oauth, jakarta-mail, smtp-auth

I have the following configuration to acquire an access token using Google's Service Account, use the access token to OAUTH2 authenticate and connect via SMTPTransport.

These are the mail session property:

```
<mailSession description="SMTP javax.mail.session" from="someone.iam.gserviceaccount.com">
    <property name="mail.smtp.host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <property name="mail.smtp.auth" value="true"/>
    <property name="mail.smtp.port" value="587"/>
    <property name="mail.smtp.ssl.enable" value="false"/>
    <property name="mail.smtp.sasl.enable" value="true"/>
    <property name="mail.smtp.ehlo" value="false"/>
    <property name="mail.smtp.sasl.mechanisms" value="XOAUTH2"/>
    <property name="mail.smtp.auth.plain.disable" value="true"/>
    <property name="mail.smtp.auth.login.disable" value="true"/>
    <property name="mail.smtp.starttls.required" value="true"/>
    <property name="mail.smtp.ssl.protocols" value="TLSv1.2"/>
    <property name="mail.smtp.connectiontimeout" value="10000"/>
</mailSession>
```

Acquire access token using Google Service Account Credentials:

```
try (FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath)) { 
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream).createScoped(Collections.singleton("https://mail.google.com/"));
    credentials.refresh();
    accessToken = credentials.getAccessToken();
    System.out.println("Access token2: " + accessToken.getTokenValue());
}
```

accessToken holds the Access token Object. I have observed the token and confirmed the structure seems valid. i.e yaxx.c.dxVaekmxICgknK

This is where the error occurs, according to documentation on JavaMail 1.5.5+, authentication is done as follows:

```
SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, null);
transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, "sender@example.com", accessToken);
```

The above fails with the following error (private values have been edited):

```
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=sample-service@gmail.iam.gserviceaccount.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Authenticate with SASL
DEBUG SMTP: SASL mechanisms allowed: XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP: SASL Mechanisms:
DEBUG SMTP:  XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP: 
DEBUG SMTP: SASL client XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP: SASL callback length: 2
DEBUG SMTP: SASL callback 0: javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback@66fdec9
DEBUG SMTP: SASL callback 1: javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback@57abad67
AUTH XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1zYW1wbGUtc2VydmljZUBnbWFpbC5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbWF1dGg9QmVhcmVyIHlhMjkuYy5iMFZoZHNTVUhBanNvSldTT0lXU3VkbHNqc25zaXVoc2xpdW5hdVNVSDEzOHJsczgzbGFqYXFhaGhzOHVzaWRmamhza3VkYWRESAo=
555 5.5.2 Syntax error, goodbye. f17-40040a170904ab9100b001922d98cb4esm19571022plr.288 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: SASL authentication failed
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:403)
```

the format of the sender and recipient are: "someone@gmail.example.com"
I am able to authenticate and thereby connect when using Google App Password (with the proper properties) but not this. I have also tried delegating users but that is not the issue. why do we get this

I have tried different formats of the mail (e.g using <>)
I have tried acquiring a G-suite in order to delegate users

I expect to be able to Transport.connect and Transport.sendMessage using OAuth2.0, i.e my service account and token passed as the password

Comment: interesting idea,  not sure why you would want to.    It should work but you need to be sure to configure domain wide deligation to the service account and delicate to a user on your google workspace domain

Comment: just curious how did you make and apps password for a service account.   service account authorization is different than oauth2 I'm ready surprised you got an access token at all

Comment: Hi @LindaLawton-DaImTo
I have configured domain wide delegation, there was a lot of push against it, given that according to google's documentation on OAuth2, DWD is optional and not needed; and a user need to setup an actual company, get a domain name and pay to access DWD.

I did not make an App Password for the service account, my apologies if my question misinformed that. I meant to communicate that I had success with authenticating and sending mail when using a regular user and App-Password (given that Basic Auth is not supported i.e username and password).

Comment: please see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account
There are two Libraries available that a user can use to get an access token for Oauth2. One would create the service account and setup so that it is live, then generate a key in JSON which contains the credentials of the service account, including private key. These are the step of (client-credential flow) what google refers to as service account.
Using GoogleCredential or ServiceAccountCredentials lib, you can acquire an access token to then use as documented here: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

I'm just not sure why you want to use a service account with the smtp server.   A service account is used by gmail both api and smtp server to access the mail accounts of users on a google workspace domain.   If you are doing that then you should use the gmail api instead of the smtp server as its much easer to use.

If you are only accessing a single users gmail account then you could do this much easer with using an apps password for that user and then you can login when ever you need.   Or you could use Oauth2 and then store the refresh token and use that when ever you need to run the script.

But to answer your question to use a service account your going to have to denote which user on your google workspace domain you want to impersonate that is done by setting `setServiceAccountUser`

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
  .setTransport(httpTransport)
  .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
  .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
  .setServiceAccountScopes(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USERS)
  .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
  .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
      new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
  .build();
```

Comment: I'll be running tests soon. I want to point that GoogleCredential is deprecated and does not support Oauth2. I will be using GoogleCredentials with "s" instead
This is for whomever may wish to follow in the future

Comment: Service account authencation isn't Oauth2 which is why i mentioned to begin with that im not even sure it will work but if you pass the access token returned it might work.     I will see if i can find some more up-to-date java code.

Comment: So I just ran some tests; I used GoogleCredentials instead of ServiceAccountCredentials. It still fails with the same syntax error

[INFO] DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=sample-service@smtpoauth2.iam.gserviceaccount.com, password=<non-null>
[INFO] DEBUG SMTP: Authenticate with SASL
[INFO] DEBUG SMTP: SASL mechanisms allowed: XOAUTH2
[INFO] DEBUG SMTP: SASL Mechanisms:
[INFO] DEBUG SMTP:  XOAUTH2
[INFO] AUTH XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1kYmEtaWNuLWFwcEBzbXRwb2=
[INFO] 555 5.5.2 Syntax error, goodbye. f17-20020ac86ed1000000b003ef2db16e72sm4715829qtv.94 - gsmtp

Comment: okay I will give it a try in the morning.    may ping the oauth team see what they have to say about this use case

Comment: Thank you very much. the syntax error should come from the foramt of AUTH XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1kYmEtaWNuLWFwcEBzbXRwb2= i.e AUTH XOAUTH2 user+Bearer access token. 
But it seems in accordance with googles documentation