sending OAuth gmail from a web server as a specific workspace user in Java
I am a google workspace administrator, and we use gmail for our domain.  I have a server-side application that sends out email as a specific gmail user, say "XXXX@mydomain.com". This application uses username and password as the required credentials for sending mail through gmail.
However, gmail is phasing out support for sending email via user name and password, and is replacing that with OAuth2 authentication.
Note that my use case does not require the user of my application to send email as him/herself. My emails are to be sent from my server as the specific workspace user "XXXX@mydomain.com". So no user interaction would take place for authentication in sending emails.
In the gmail documentation https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending, there is a sample program, gmail/snippets/src/main/java/SendMessage.java, which I believe is the template for sending email from a server-side program through gmail via OAuth.
Am I correct in assuming that this sample program is the template I should use for my use case?
If so, I am not sure how to set up and make available the required OAuth credentials to my program.  Below is my incomplete understanding of the process. I would appreciate advice on completing my understanding of this process.
Step 1. Create a project. The link https://developers.google.com/identity given in the sample program leads to the following page which shows how to use the Google API Console to create a project.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/policy-compliance
Step 2. Create credentials and download them as the file: client_secret.json.  The instructions at: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server show how to create OAuth credentials for the project.
Question 1. This step requires that a redirect URI to be provided. However, in my use case, the user is not involved in the authentication process. So no redirection need take place. Is the redirect URI still necessary but will not be used in my use case?
Step 3. Use the OAuth credentials in the sample program.
The first statement of the sendEmail program gets the credentials:
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
.createScoped(GmailScopes.GMAIL_SEND);
The documentation for getApplicationDefault states that this call can get the credentials from a file specified in the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.
Question 2: Is the credentials file referred to by this environment variable the same as the client_secret.json produced in the credentials creation step above? If not, what should it contain?
Many thanks.
Azad
code
public void sendMail(String recipientEmail, String subject, String text) throws Exception {
        String password = properties.getProperty(MAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD);
        MimeMessage message = buildMessage(recipientEmail, subject, text);
        String mailHost = properties.getProperty(MAIL_SMTP_HOST);
        try {
            this.transport.connect(mailHost, this.senderEmail, password);
            this.transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        }


Can we be 100% clear that you are sending from a workspace domain user?   If so you should consider using a service account it will be much easer.    Can i see the code you are using now to send the emails.  I may have an example you can try.

Yes my server is sending mail as a google workspace user.

Here is the basic code I am using currently:

public void sendMail(String recipientEmail, String subject, String text) throws Exception {
String password = properties.getProperty(MAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD);
MimeMessage message = buildMessage(recipientEmail, subject, text);
String mailHost = properties.getProperty(MAIL_SMTP_HOST);
try {
this.transport.connect(mailHost, this.senderEmail, password);
this.transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
}

Let me know if you need more details.

Apologies for be unaware of how to format code in stackoverflow comments. Would appreciate directions.

Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76094898/1841839   You need to configure domain wide deligation

Thank you for your insights.
I can create a service account and make it a delegate. But 'GoogleCredential', shown in your post, is deprecated. So I am not sure how to create non-deprecated credentials and provide it with the data it needs.
For example, assuming 'GoogleCredentials' is to be used instead, its getApplicationDefault() call would need a credentials file. But I don't know how to create that file. Is that documented somewhere?
I guess what would be most helpful, if available, is non-deprecated sample code for getting the credentials.
Many thanks.
Azad

I created a service account, made it a delegate, created a key pair for it, and downloaded the resulting .json file. For scope I gave it https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send.
To create undeprecated credentials, I believe I can use the ServiceAccountsCredentials class's fromStream(InputStream credentialsStream), where the stream represents the file downloaded upon key pair generation.  Finally, to impersonate my specific workspace user, I can use the call createDelegated("XXXX@mydomain.com").
So far so good?
How should I then use the credentials to send email via gmail?

I got the above procedure for sending emails via a service account working by using ServiceAccountCredentials created from the downloaded credentials file. To actually send an email, I needed to create a Gmail object that is aware of the credentials, by using Gmail.Builder. Then the gmail object is used to send a message like this: gmail.users().messages().send("me", message).execute();
